# How to get the real part of a complex function with some real coefficients?

Tags: differential-equations, functions, simplifying-expressions, complex, algebra

I want to get the real part of the function `n3[t]` (see below) which is the solution to a differential equation.

Solve the differential equation. (Suppose `m`, `k`, `f`, and `t` are real)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {m*n1''[t] + k*n1[t] - k*n2[t] == f*E^(I*w*t), 
   m*n2''[t] - k*n1[t] + 2*k*n2[t] - k*n3[t] == 0, 
   m*n3''[t] - k*n2[t] + k*n3[t] == 0, n1[0] == 0, n2[0] == 0, 
   n3[0] == 0, n1'[0] == 0, n2'[0] == 0, n3'[0] == 0};

(sol = DSolve[eqns, {n1, n2, n3}, t]) // Short[#, 5] &
```

Simplify the solution

```
solt = {n1[t], n2[t], n3[t]} /. sol // FullSimplify
```

I got
[image]

Then I tried to get the real part of n3[t] with `ComplexExpand[]`, but I failed. It seems that m and k are also regarded as complex numbers. (The output is actually very long, I omit the rest of it)
[image]

I failed to get the real part of n3[t] directly with `Re[]` either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, try this:

```
expr = ExpandAll[solt][[1]];
```

And then the following:

```
Refine[ComplexExpand[Re[expr]], Assumptions -> {f > 0, k > 0, m > 0, t > 0, w > 0}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I ran your codes and it works. But could you explain why your codes succeed by using `ComplexExpand` and `Re` together, while I failed when I used either `ComplexExpand` or `Re` alone?

Comment: I also tried `ComplexExpand[Re[expr]] // Simplify` but it took my computer too much time to run this code. But why does `Refine` make such a big difference that it doesn't take the computer a lot of time to run `Refine[ComplexExpand[Re[expr]], Assumptions -> {f > 0, k > 0, m > 0, t > 0, w > 0}] // Simplify`?

Comment: Besides, I am sorry for my late reply. I was really busy with other things in the past few weeks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept your answer half a year ago because I didn't know how to use stack exchange at that time.